# Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas where some of the numbers are expressed in scientific notation (or exponent notation) like this:

```
                  id        value
id              1.00    -4.22e-01
value          -0.42     1.00e+00
percent        -0.72     1.00e-01
played          0.03    -4.35e-02
money          -0.22     3.37e-01
other            NaN          NaN
sy             -0.03     2.19e-04
sz             -0.33     3.83e-01
```

And the scientific notation makes what should be an easy comparison, needlessly difficult. I assume it's the 21900 value that's screwing it up for the others. I mean 1.0 is encoded. ONE!

This doesn't work:

```
np.set_printoptions(supress=True)
```

And `pandas.set_printoptions` doesn't implement suppress either, and I've looked all at `pd.describe_options()` in despair, and `pd.core.format.set_eng_float_format()` only seems to turn it on for all the other float values, with no ability to turn it off.

Comment: Dd you fix the typo in `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)` - two p's in suppress?

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened because it has the best answer and was asked earlier than the one it was closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @JosiahYoder, Just because it is closed, doesnt mean it is deleted.  It just stops more answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your data is probably `object` dtype. This is a direct copy/paste of your data. `read_csv` interprets it as the correct dtype. You should normally only have `object` dtype on string-like fields.

```
In [5]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
           id     value
id       1.00 -0.422000
value   -0.42  1.000000
percent -0.72  0.100000
played   0.03 -0.043500
money   -0.22  0.337000
other     NaN       NaN
sy      -0.03  0.000219
sz      -0.33  0.383000
```

check if your dtypes are `object`

```
In [7]: df.dtypes
Out[7]: 
id       float64
value    float64
dtype: object
```

This converts this frame to `object` dtype (notice the printing is funny now)

```
In [8]: df.astype(object)
Out[8]: 
           id     value
id          1    -0.422
value   -0.42         1
percent -0.72       0.1
played   0.03   -0.0435
money   -0.22     0.337
other     NaN       NaN
sy      -0.03  0.000219
sz      -0.33     0.383
```

This is how to convert it back (`astype(float)`) also works here

```
In [9]: df.astype(object).convert_objects()
Out[9]: 
           id     value
id       1.00 -0.422000
value   -0.42  1.000000
percent -0.72  0.100000
played   0.03 -0.043500
money   -0.22  0.337000
other     NaN       NaN
sy      -0.03  0.000219
sz      -0.33  0.383000
```

This is what an `object` dtype frame would look like

```
In [10]: df.astype(object).dtypes
Out[10]: 
id       object
value    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Actually the column was int64, that had then been df.corr() 'd which returns all float64s

Comment: if you have NaN in the column it could NOT have been int64; only float64 or object

Comment: df.corr() returns NaNs when the stddev of a column is 0.

Comment: they may have started out as ``Int64`` but they are ``float64`` by definition. However, if they were actually object to begin with, then they still might be ``object``

Answer (score 107):

quick temporary: `df.round(4)`

global: `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format`

The `:20` means the total width should be twenty characters, padded with whitespace on the left if it would otherwise be shorter. You can use simply `'{:,.2f}'` if you don't want to specify the number.

The `.2f` means that there should be two digits after the decimal point, even if they are zeros.

For more custom and advanced styling, see [Apply Formatting to Each Column in Dataframe Using a Dict Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32744997/3140992), [pandas table styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Table-Visualization) and [pandas format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html).

For example you can do `df.style.format(precision=2)`, format each column `dfg.style.format({'column_pct':'{:.1%}'})` and many other useful things. Note `df.style` only works in jupyter but [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745072/3140992) lets you store the results in the dataframe to display in the console as well.

Comment: try this experiment: `print('{:20,.8f}'.format(12333344445676.0123456789))`, then adjust the 20 to 40 and see what happens and I think you'll have your answer.  you can use this same style formatter on numbers in a print statement.

Comment: Fwiw you might also want to [suppress the data type output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295451/suppress-descriptive-output-when-printing-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Agree with @Bouncner, I also tried many solutions but found that only this solution can print a specific number of decimal points for float values in pandas as expected.

Comment: Great! For scientific notation, use `'{:e}'.format`

Answer (score 7):

Try this which will give you scientific notation only for large and very small values (and adds a thousands separator unless you omit the ","):

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%,g' % x)
```

Or to almost completely suppress scientific notation without losing precision, try this:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)
```

Answer (score 3):

quick fix without rounding:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use the values as formated string in a list, say as part of csvfile csv.writier, the numbers can be formated before creating a list:

```
df['label'].apply(lambda x: '%.17f' % x).values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the options like

1. pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.4f}'.format
2. pd.set_option('display.float_format', str)
3. pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: f'%.{len(str(x%1))-2}f' % x)
4. pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

but nothing worked for me.

so while assigning the variable / value (var1) to a variable (say num1) I used round(val,5).

```
num1 = round(var1,5)
```

This is a crude method as you have to use this round function in each assignment.  But this ensures you control on how it happens and get what you want.