# Two type of variable types in One column & one is in suppressesed Scientific Notation: pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a column which can have two type of data types varchar and float. Now since my float is a long number such as 10154346483399200, which becomes lately like 1.01543E+16 and the other entry could be like UPDATE-c1038-6036456184586739712. How to bring the 'E' data entries in their original form

so

```
In[3] a= ['1.01543E+16', 'UPDATE-c1038-6036456184586739712']
```

answer should be something like

```
['10154346483399200', 'UPDATE-c1038-6036456184586739712']
```

Applying just to solve suppressing Scientific Notation gives me an error

```
 df.apply(lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

TypeError: float argument required, not str
```

Every help will be appreciating

Comment: Sorry are these strings or really float here? As it stands what you've shown is a string, there is no way to get back to the original value from that

Comment: First one is float, I just made it up for creating an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format / Suppress Scientific Notation from Python Pandas Aggregation Results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)

Comment: Since I have a two type of variables, so applying df.apply(lambda x: '%.3f' % x) gives me an error : TypeError: float argument required, not str

Comment: Does the columns contains values as list?

Comment: Single column- that's a problem

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe?