# Pandas dataframe - data type issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a `pd.DataFrame`, but I am having trouble getting the data type correct. I have two `numpy` arrays that are type `float`.

They were created from a list of coordinates (x & y) as seen here:

```
# Take coordinates from list and convert to a numpy array
x_vector = np.asarray(x_list, dtype=float)
y_vector = np.asarray(y_list, dtype=float)
```

For reference here is a sample of what `x_vector` looks like:

```
[-2248925.48185815 -2248925.48185815 -2248080.13621823 -2262432.04991849
-2250570.32692157 -2237312.76315587 -2237312.76315587 -2245650.16260083
-2245650.16260083 -2249323.93572129 -2247050.83128422 -2253151.83634956]
```

I am pleased with the formatting here, the issue arises when I try to add `x_vector` and `y_vector` to the pandas data frame.

My logic is that I have 201 records of lat/lons so my `index` equals that, then I add `columns` corresponding to my data, finally I set the `dtype` to match my coordinates (float).

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, 202, 1), columns=['lat', 'lon', 'ws_daily_max'], dtype=float)

df['lat'] = y_vector
df['lon'] = x_vector
```

However when I print `df` to the console, I get these values where the decimal place shifted significantly. What went wrong, why did the lat/lon values change? I was expecting them to be the same as the float values above, i.e. (`-2248925.48185815`)?

`index         lat           lon      ws_daily_max
1    1.895464e+06 -2.248925e+06           NaN
2    1.895464e+06 -2.248925e+06           NaN`

I am truly confused as to what happened. No error message printed, but this is *not* the result I was expecting. Any clarity as to why and how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Help me, StackExchange. You're my only hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the scientific notation of the same number. 1.895464e+06 means 1.895464*10^6 = 1895465. So the decimal place did not shift, just the representation. If you want to change the looks of the numbers, look at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html. I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. Note that the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results) shows exactly how to do so.

Comment: @AmiTavory interesting, although I agree with the accepted answer on that thread, converting to string for aesthetic purposes is not a best practice.

Comment: @Nikolai I believe the person answering there agreed with you completely on that. Note the first part of the answer, though - `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)` - that just sets the display option.