# read txt file with scientifc notations to pandas dataframe in scientific notation

Tags: python, pandas, scientific-notation

is there a way to keep scientific notation consistent in txt file and after reading it to pandas dataframe.

`pd.read_csv(physio_files[1], sep=" ", header = None)`

above command is suppressing scientific notation.

Comment: Scientific notation is an external representation of a number, not an internal property. You can display any floating point number in either scientific or fixed-point notation, it is your choice, not pandas'.

Comment: @DYZ i agree. But how can i make pandas display in scientific notation instead of default fixed point notation?

Comment: This question (especially the first answer) may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results

Comment: @DYZ the answer shows how to suppress scientific notation exactly opposite to what i intend to

Comment: The answer explains how _"you can specify your own string converter..."_ Which could be a converter to the scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(1000000., range(5), range(5))
print(df)

           0          1          2          3          4
0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0
1  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0
2  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0
3  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0
4  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0  1000000.0
```

---

You can control the formatting using pandas `'displat.float_format'` option.  You can also assume a value for that option temporarily using `pd.option_context`

Use `'{:0.4e}'.format` as your custom formatter.  Change the `4` to suit your needs.

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:0.4e}'.format):
    print(df)

           0          1          2          3          4
0 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06
1 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06
2 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06
3 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06
4 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06 1.0000e+06
```