# pandas - How to extract a value(s) from a list stored in rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I feel that the solution to this problem is really simple, but I am unable to figure it out.
So, I have a Pandas DataFrame, a screenshot of which is as below:
[image]

Column names do not matter, so I just excluded them from the pic. What is important though, is that I have a list of values in the first column. Now, if you look at the lower part of the image, it has a list with the values: `[Bolivia , Plurinational State of)]`. I am trying to take the first value from that list i.e. `Bolivia` and save it in the same row instead of that list. If I use something like energy["Country"][0] (The name of the concerned column is "Country"), I can extract the value, and it will also extract the required values from other rows, since there is only one value in that list. But for some reason I get an error.

Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def answer_one():

    energy = pd.read_excel('Energy Indicators.xls',
                  sheet_name='Energy',
                  skiprows=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17],
                  skipfooter=38,
                  header=9, 
                  parse_cols=[2,3,4,5], na_values = "...")

    energy.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    energy["Energy Supply"] = energy["Energy Supply"].mul(1000000)
    energy["Country"] = energy["Country"].str.split("(")[0]

    return energy

answer_one()
```

It is the trailing `[0]` at the end of `energy["Country"] = energy["Country"].str.split("(")` which is making the trouble. The error I get is as follows:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Is there a way around this?

Also, a little another query: Is there a way to expand the width of the second column so that values like 1.430000e+08 could be displayed in their natural form?

(The full file "Energy Indicator.xls" can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Pb50j1RlghSspsjcQV3_RVG-nCIB9lg))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) for select first value of `list`s:

```
energy["Country"] = energy["Country"].str.split("(").str[0]
```

Comment: Bro... You are a savior.. Where the heck did you learn Python man? Can you please share it? Tried to accept your answer, but it won't let me in 11 minutes.

Comment: My learning is not so quick, it is more years of answering in SO... You are welcome!

Comment: Where did you find the trailing "()"? In which row?

Comment: Yea, you confused me.

Comment: Anyway, can you also please suggest how can I increase the column width, so that I can see 321000000 instead of 3.2100000e+08??

Comment: I think you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21137150/2901002)