# How to get value from Panda Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have an 200 rows in Pandas Serias `all_data['close']` and need to compare few last rows with `m_a` last rows. Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from talib import SMA

all_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'open': [item[1] for item in data],
    'close': [item[4] for item in data],
})

m_a = SMA(all_data['close'], timeperiod=5)
```

From here I need to find a way how to compare values from `all_data['close']` and `m_a`. I tried this way:

```
print(m_a[-1:])
```

But I only can get this value:

```
199   0.00001103  
dtype: float64
```

I need that number `- 0.00001103`, so if I make something like this

```
print(m_a[-1:].item())
```

I get a value like this `1.1027070707070725e-05` and it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: 1.1027070707070725e-05 =  0.00001103

Comment: `print("{:.10f}".format(m_a[-1:].item()))` - replacing 10 with whatever level of precision you want to display.

Comment: This is called scientific notation. Didn't try it myself but maybe the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results) question is helpful? It basically says that you can change the settings in pandas to surpress scientific notation like this: `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)`

Comment: @Nihal thank you, that's the trick. So I can easily compare it by indexes.