# How to replace only null values in column 2 with dictionary values by matching column 1 to key in dictionary? Conditional find Conditional replace

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to replace null values only in column 2 with dictionary values by matching values in column 1 with keys in dictionary.

```
Country Rate    Tax Rate
Algeria 2.00%   76.90%
Angola  5.00%    null
Algeria 2.00%    null
Angola  5.00%    null
Algeria 2.10%   76.90%
Angola  4.90%   52.10%
Algeria 2.20%   76.90%
```

1. I calculated the mean Tax Rate buy Country.
2. I dropped all countries that didn't have a mean calculation: all values null
3. I created a dict from results {country, TR(mean)} = (k,v)
4. I created code that replaces values in Tax Rate to matching country in dict

**NOTE:  it replaces all values in Tax Rate not just null values**

```
tr = df.groupby('country')['tax rate'].mean()
tr.dropna(inplace=True)
tr_dict = tr.to_dict()
df['tax rate'] = df['country'].apply(lambda x: tr_dict.get(x))
```

**results**

```
Country Rate    Tax Rate
Algeria 2.00%   mean of Algeria
Angola  5.00%   mean of Angola
Algeria 2.00%   mean of Algeria 
Angola  5.00%   mean of Angola 
Algeria 2.10%   mean of Algeria
Angola  4.90%   mean of Angola
Algeria 2.20%   mean of Algeria
```

I believe I am missing something at the end of this code as it is correctly replacing the values by 'country' but it is replacing all 'tax rate' values and I only need it to replace null values only.

*** Expected results***

```
Country Rate    Tax Rate
Algeria 2.00%   76.90%
Angola  5.00%    mean of Angola
Algeria 2.00%    mean of Algeria
Angola  5.00%    mean of Angola
Algeria 2.10%   76.90%
Angola  4.90%   52.10%
Algeria 2.20%   76.90%
```

Comment: I suggest you store your numbers as a numeric type and not strings, `df['Rate'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Rate'].str.strip('%'), errors='coerce')`, if you expect to do math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `transform` and using `fillna`

```
df['tax rate']=df['tax rate'].fillna(df.groupby('country')['tax rate'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: The last issue: how to I prevent mean results from converting to a scientific number? or convert it back to a int from scientific number?

Comment: @SmitDataDawg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results

Comment: Thanks again, that was exactly what I was looking for as previous searches turned up fixes that were not that simple.  Thanks for your help.