# Set non-scientific float representation as default floating point format for pandas

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

First, let me say that I've seen --

[Format / Suppress Scientific Notation from Python Pandas Aggregation Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)

and tried those things that are mentioned in this question as you can see below, and yet I get the same e+ notation.

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format

test_df.median().values

array([-1.2e+02,  3.4e+01,  2.9e+01,  2.1e+03,  4.4e+02,  1.2e+03,
        4.1e+02,  3.5e+00,  1.8e+05,  3.0e+00])
```

OR

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)

test_df.median().values

array([-1.2e+02,  3.4e+01,  2.9e+01,  2.1e+03,  4.4e+02,  1.2e+03,
        4.1e+02,  3.5e+00,  1.8e+05,  3.0e+00])
```

How do I get the floats in the array ex.  `2.9e+01` as `29.` etc.

I don't want to see output in scientific format by default, unless I explicitly set it.

Comment: You need `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.2f' % x)`.

Comment: @harvpan as you can see I have tried this as well, but I get the same results.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ? Are you sure you executing all the cells after you make the change?

Comment: @harvpan pd.set_option... and test_df.median().values are in the same cell.