# Converting .csv file into scientific notation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scientific-notation

I'm trying to convert csv files with pandas.

```
def convert_file(file, columns, name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, delimiter=',')
    df.drop(df.columns[columns], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.to_csv(name, index=False, header=False)
```

After dropping the columns I don't need I want to bring the numbers into scientific format.
What options do I have?

Example:

current result -> desired result

0.0053455117   -> 5.3455117e-003

0.88455491     -> 8.8455491e-001

10.576477      -> 1.0576477e+001

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What options do I have?*

Harness `float_format` of [`.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[0.1,0.01,0.001]})
df.to_csv("file.csv",float_format="%e",header=False,index=False)
```

produces `file.csv`

```
1.000000e-01
1.000000e-02
1.000000e-03
```