# (Pandas) df.mean() return weird values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

input
`df.mean()`
output:

```
a       4.112657e+07
b       1.197258e+00
c       4.172984e+05
d       2.461237e+02
```

input

```
df["a"].mean()
```

(correct) output:

```
41126569.99462365
```

type values in "a" col = int
others col have str values
**why is this happening**

Comment: use `astype(float)`

Comment: This is question is duplicate of [Format / Suppress Scientific Notation from Python Pandas Aggregation Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)

Answer (score 1):

They are the same numbers, the thing is that the output its written in scientific notation. If you want the typical notation, you can use something like this: [Format / Suppress Scientific Notation from Python Pandas Aggregation Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results)

Answer (score 0):

`4.112657e+07` and `41126569.99462365` are the same number. The first is just using [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).

Comment: :O you're right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the mean of the other column, you have to change their type from `str` to `float`. Put `.astype(float)` to change the type to float, after that, you can do the mean.