# Divide a column(containing both negative numbers and positive numbers) of a Pandas Dataframe with a specific number and create a new column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A  = 49531.78, -3.178 ,-2.119

Want to divide A's value with 49939.203 , used formula in excel =IFERROR(49939.203/A1,0)
B should be => 1.01;-15714.04; -23567.35 , how should I do in python to get this division ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.rdiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rdiv.html) for divide from right side:

```
df['B'] = df.A.rdiv(49939.203).replace(np.inf, 0).round(2)
print (df)
           A         B
0  49531.780      1.01
1     -3.178 -15714.03
2     -2.119 -23567.34
3      0.000      0.00
```

Comment: Thanks for this response, How to handle 0 if in A column ? Want the negative signs as well in B? @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael

Comment: @AnjaliKushwaha - you can use `replace` like `df['B'] = df.A.abs().rdiv(49939.203).replace(np.inf, 0).round(2)`

Comment: Now i want to divide this B column like this ---- =IFERROR(691.525/B,0). Will this above logic work, like denominator and numerator is changed little???

Comment: @AnjaliKushwaha - sure, if change `49939.203` to `691.525` it working well

Comment: Thanks alot, its working, may i know what is rdiv() function really do?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael, how to convert this series to normal dataframe column as I am getting exponential format in few values?

Comment: @AnjaliKushwaha - `what is rdiv() function really do` ? `df.A.rdiv(49939.203)` is same like `49939.203 / df.A` divide from right side

Comment: @AnjaliKushwaha - it is more complicated, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results) for remove `exponential format`