# Is there a way to save numpy set print options?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scientific-notation

I like to avoid scientific notation and so I regularly use this command `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True, formatter={'float_kind':'{:0.4f}'.format}, linewidth=130)`

(For others having the issue suppressing scientific notation with pandas dataframes, this line suppresses scientific notation for both packages).

Is there a way to save this as the default printing options? Or is there a file I can write this to so it loads with python, numpy or anaconda?

Comment: On the plus side, I have this command saved somewhere for later use!

Comment: Related but different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-pandas-aggregation-results?rq=1