# mean of a column after group by returns nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
df = name   year.   salary.   d.   
     a      1990.     3.       5
     b      1992.     90.      1 
     c      1990.     234.     3 
     ...
```

I am trying to group my data frame based on year, and then get the average of the salaries in that year. Then my goal is to assign it to a new column. This is what I do:

```
df['averageSalaryPerYear'] = df.groupby('year')['salary'].mean()
```

I do get the correct results for df.groupby('year')['salary'].mean(), since when I print them, I get a column of numbers in scientific notation. However, when I assign it to df['averageSalaryPerYear'], they all turn into nan. I am not sure why this is happening as the printed values seem to be fine, although they are in scientific notation like this:

1990    1.707235e+07

1991    2.357879e+07

1992    3.098244e+07

which is year and avgOfSalary

Why is this happening? I want my new column to show the correct results of averages.
...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `groupby` the length of rows are different so you can't add it as new column.

Try `transform`.

```py
df['averageSalaryPerYear'] = df.groupby('year')['salary'].transform(np.mean)
```

Comment: And is there anyway to save the values as a regular float instead of this scientific notation? It is probably a float under the hood, but I want it to be displayed in the columns as floats too @Shuo

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-pandas-aggregation-results).