# Pandas read csv data type

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a csv with pandas using the read_csv command.  However, one of my columns is a 15 digit number which is read in as a float and then truncated to exponential notation.  So the entries in this column become 2.09228E+14 instead of the 15 digit number I want.  I've tried reading it as a string, but I get '2.09228E+14' instead of the number.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it would be easier to just format the cells to not display in scientific notation - if they are coming from an excel document first

Comment: This is a duplicate. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas

Comment: This is just a display issue, the data is still a float, to change the float precision use `pandas.set_option('display.precision', 15)`

Answer (score 1):

Just do
`str(int(float('2.09228E+14')))` which should give you `'209228000000000'`

Comment: assuming it's a str that you want