# Apply Formatting to Each Column in Dataframe Using a Dict Mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, formatting, dataframe

**Problem Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Currency': {0: 111.23, 1: 321.23},
                   'Int': {0: 23, 1: 3},
                   'Rate': {0: 0.03030, 1: 0.09840}}
            )
```

Produces the following DataFrame

```
   Currency  Int    Rate
0    111.23   23  0.0303
1    321.23    3  0.0984
```

I want to apply very specific formatting to each column in the dataframe using a dict like the following:

```
format_mapping={'Currency': '${:,.2f}', 'Int': '{:,.0f}', 'Rate': '{:.2f}%'}
```

I know I can use applymap for multiple columns or apply on a single column:

```
#All columns
df = df.applymap('{:.2f}%'.format)
#Specific columns
df['Rate'] = df['Rate'].apply('{:.2f}%'.format)
```

**Question**

How can I iterate through each column in a dataframe and apply formatting using a dictionary where the `dict` `key` is the `column` and the `value` is the `string` formatting?

End result would look like this (ignore the fact that percent wasn't multiplied by 100 for now)

```
  Currency Int   Rate
0  $111.23  23  0.03%
1  $321.23   3  0.10%
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way would be to iterate through the `format_mapping` dictionary and then apply on the column (denoted by the key) the formatting denoted by the `value`. Example -

```
for key, value in format_mapping.items():
    df[key] = df[key].apply(value.format)
```

Demo -

```
In [62]: df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Currency': {0: 111.23, 1: 321.23},
   ....:                    'Int': {0: 23, 1: 3},
   ....:                    'Rate': {0: 0.03030, 1: 0.09840}}
   ....:             )

In [63]:

In [63]: format_mapping={'Currency': '${:,.2f}', 'Int': '{:,.0f}', 'Rate': '{:.2f}%'}

In [64]: for key, value in format_mapping.items():
   ....:     df[key] = df[key].apply(value.format)
   ....:

In [65]: df
Out[65]:
  Currency Int   Rate
0  $111.23  23  0.03%
1  $321.23   3  0.10%
```

Answer (score 18):

In 2021 (Pandas 1.2.3) you can use `df.style.format()`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Currency": {0: 111.23, 1: 321.23},
        "Int": {0: 23, 1: 3},
        "Rate": {0: 0.03030, 1: 0.09840},
    }
)
format_mapping = {"Currency": "${:,.2f}", "Int": "{:,.0f}", "Rate": "{:.2f}%"}

df.style.format(format_mapping)
```

[image: styled pandas dataframe]

More information: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values

Comment: Unlike the .apply solution there does not seem to make a way to make it "permanent", it only seemed to work in jupyter notebooks and can only be applied prior to displaying the table. But there are some useful advanced styling options.

Comment: With `apply` you change the data itself. With `style.format` you change how the data is displayed.