# How to export Python dataframe columns with number as integers with comma separators, and be able to sum/divide/multiply them?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have a dataframe with several columns with numbers. I'd like to export them as integers but with comma separators for numbers over 999.

I was able to do it, but when they are exported I'm not able to manipulate the numbers, as if they turn to strings because of the comma.

I tried this with no luck:

```
format_mapping={'Balance': '{:,.0f}'}

for key, value in format_mapping.items():
   cash_tracker_df[key] = cash_tracker_df[key].apply(value.format)
```

I read the following to get where I'm at:

[Python Pandas Apply Formatting to Each Column in Dataframe Using a Dict Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744997/python-pandas-apply-formatting-to-each-column-in-dataframe-using-a-dict-mapping)

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial02.html

I used pandas and xlsxwriter.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, are you saying that when you open the exported file in Excel, that you want the cells in the balance column to have a number format with a thousands separator?

Comment: @EricTruett Yes exactly. I was able to add the comma, but then I am not able to use the numbers like add and subtract them...as if they turned to strings with the comma. It is for the balance and a few other columns in the df/excel.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the *num_format* property when you are defining the format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,1000,1001,10000,10001]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

cellFormat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 10, cellFormat)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Finally if you want to use a decimal separator as well you should use

> 'num_format': '#,##.00'

For more info have a look [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_num_format)

Comment: Thank you. This is definitely hopeful. Unfortunately it is still not working.

I wrote:
```
cellFormat = cash_tracker_df.add_format({'num_format': '#,##'})
cash_tracker_df.set_column('Balance', 10, cellFormat)
```
I get: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'add_format'

What can I do now?

Comment: You shouldn't call the add_format method on panda's df but on xlsxwriter's workbook object. Have a look here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html and at my example code to see how to create a workbook object and then define its format.  I wouldn't recommend to use pandas for formatting. In general you want to finish with your data manipulation in pandas and then either pass the df into xlsxwriter to start formatting it or create a macro.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a hard time understanding. What do you mean "shouldn't call the add_format method on panda's df but on xlsxwriter's workbook object."? I don't need to create a workbook object because everything I have was imported from Excel and put into a dataframe. Could you please elaborate? Thank you

Comment: Let me ask you this so that i can better understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to output the dataframe as an excel file with the appropriate formatting, like in the output picture in my answer? In that case you should use pandas+xlsxwriter. Or you just want to preview the dataframe with comma separator in your IDE?

Comment: I want to output the df as an excel with formatting like your picture. 
I'm also still researching...would xlwings be useful?

Comment: Then you should use pandas for the data manipulation and xlsxwriter for formatting. There are plenty of examples and documentation for these technologies, you just need to devote some time and do your research. I haven't used xlwings so i don't know. I would go with xlsxwriter or openpyxl because they are the 2 most popular libraries on this matter. I decided to go with xlsxwriter and it hasn't let me down.