# Pandas Display Format on a specific column

Tags: pandas, formatting

So I want to display a single column with a currency format. Basically with a dollar sign, thousand comma separators, and two decimal places.

Input:

```
Invoice    Name       Amount      Tax
0001       Best Buy   1324        .08
0002       Target     1238593.1   .12 
0003       Walmart    10.32       .55
```

Output:

```
Invoice    Name       Amount           Tax
0001       Best Buy       $1,324.00    .08
0002       Target     $1,238,593.10    .12 
0003       Walmart           $10.32    .55
```

Note: I still want to be able to do calculations on it, so it would only be a display feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Apply Formatting to Each Column in Dataframe Using a Dict Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744997/python-pandas-apply-formatting-to-each-column-in-dataframe-using-a-dict-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just format to print out, you can try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: [f'${y:,}'for y in x] if x.name=='Amount' else x)
```

which creates a new dataframe that looks like:

```
   Invoice      Name        Amount   Tax
0        1  Best Buy      $1,324.0  0.08
1        2    Target  $1,238,593.1  0.12
2        3   Walmart        $10.32  0.55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this line (before printing your data frame of course):

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.2f}'.format
```

it will print your columns in the data frame (but only float columns ) like  this :

```
$12,500.00
```