# Format a number with commas to separate thousands

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, number-formatting

I have a large dataframe, which has a column called `Lead Rev`. This column is a field of numbers such as (100000 or 5000 etc.) I want to know how to format these numbers to show commas as thousand separators. The dataset has over 200,000 rows.

Is it something like: `'{:,}'.format('Lead Rev')`

which gives this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-5fe9c827d80b> in <module>()
----> 1 '{:,}'.format('Lead Rev')

ValueError: Cannot specify ',' or '_' with 's'.
```

Comment: When you say 'numbers', are they int, float or both? Also, the [format spec `'{:,}'` doesn't contain any type '%'/'f'/etc., so it will default to 's' and try to apply it to all types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). That's *supposed* to work, but if it doesn't, you'd have to fall back to column-specific, type-specific format specifiers/ custom formatters. It helps when reporting issues to say which version of pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas)

Comment: This question isn't *exactly* a duplicate of the question I just voted to close it towards, but it's a subset of the topic and fully answered by the top-voted question there.

Answer (score 77):

To make all your floats show comma separators by default in pandas versions 0.23 through 0.25 set the following:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,}'.format
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/options.html

In pandas version 1.0 this leads to some strange formatting in some cases.

Comment: add ".2f" after comma will show only 2 digits other than some strange float-style digits.
`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format`

Comment: Seems doesn't work for `int` .

Comment: Please include the first upvoted comment into your answer.  The .2f is a very nice default when including thousands.

Answer (score 46):

`df.head().style.format("{:,.0f}")` (*for all columns*)

`df.head().style.format({"col1": "{:,.0f}", "col2": "{:,.0f}"})` (*per column*)

https://pbpython.com/styling-pandas.html

Comment: This answer won't change the values.  It is strictly for presentation. Perfect.  Thank you.  - E

Comment: FYI, this requires jinja2: `ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'jinja2'. DataFrame.style requires jinja2. Use pip or conda to install jinja2.`

Comment: @Henry - which IDE/Notebook client are you using? For a standard Jupyter Lab or Jupyter Notebook installation and `pip install pandas` this works out of the box.

Answer (score 43):

You can use apply() to get the desired result. This works with floating too

```
import pandas as pd

series1 = pd.Series({'Value': 353254})
series2 = pd.Series({'Value': 54464.43})
series3 = pd.Series({'Value': 6381763761})

df = pd.DataFrame([series1, series2, series3])
print(df.head())

         Value
0  3.532540e+05
1  5.446443e+04
2  6.381764e+09

df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x['Value']), axis=1)
print(df.head())

             Value
0        353,254.0
1        54,464.43
2  6,381,763,761.0
```

Comment: How is it different with `df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply(lambda x: "{:,}".format(x)`?

Comment: What if you want to have two decimals only? How do you incorporate the `%.2f` information?

Comment: This answer is misleading because it results in a column that is a string instead of a float.

Comment: You can take the lambda out of it altogether, too.: `df['Value'] = df['Value'].apply('{:,}'.format)` since that str.format takes one argument.

Comment: How to make it apply to `int` as well?

Answer (score 20):

**Easiest method is**

```
df = df.style.format('{:,}')
```

Answer (score 7):

In Pandas version > 1.3.0, you can set the thousands separator either globally:

```
pd.set_option("styler.format.thousands", ",")
```

or for a specific dataframe:

```
df.style.format(thousands=",")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html

Answer (score 6):

Possibly the most concise solution: `df[column].map('{:,d}'.format)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply or stack method

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
df.stack().str.replace(',','.').unstack()
```