# How to insert a comma as a thousands separator in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I'm trying to format the Dollar Amount column to have a comma thousands separator for easier viewing, but I haven't been able to figure it out. Can someone please show me the way?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx') 
df['Dollar Amount'].head()

Index  Dollar Amount
0      5721.48
1      4000.00
2      4769.00
3       824.07
4       643.60
5       620.00

Name: Dollar Amount, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format a number with commas to separate thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-with-commas-to-separate-thousands)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Notice it will convert your `float` type to `object`

```
df.DollarAmount.apply(lambda x : "{:,}".format(x))
Out[509]: 
0    5,721.48
1     4,000.0
2     4,769.0
3      824.07
4       643.6
5       620.0
Name: DollarAmount, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change one thing since it was a Pandas dataframe.

    `df['Dollar Amount'].apply(lambda x : "{:,}".format(x))`

Comment: @ACH aha, You got it :-)

Comment: how it is inserting (,) on the right position ? where are you giving the position?

Comment: @pyd  `:,` here  adding the comma for 1k.

Comment: @pyd you can check the link :-) https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html (By searching {:,} you will see the result )

Comment: Up to date documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Comment: Hi, how to apply across multiple columns?

Comment: @user3423407 df.apply(lambda x : "{:,}".format(x),1)

Comment: I strongly prefer to set this globally, as in [another answer to a closely-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52405666/1048186), and especially in [this comment on that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-with-commas-to-separate-thousands#comment111739550_52405666): `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format`  For one thing, it works on all columns of any dataframes printed after you run this.

Answer (score 10):

This is a more pandorable way to get the thousands separator.

```
df['Dollar Amount']=df['Dollar Amount'].apply('{:,}'.format)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `locale` that might help, as long as you're okay with formatting your numbers as strings:

```
import pandas as pd
import locale as lc

# Get the list of all locale options
all_locales = lc.locale_alias
# I'll use US conventions since that's what you mentioned in your question
lc.setlocale(lc.LC_ALL,all_locales["en_us"])

df = pd.DataFrame({"Dollar Amount":[1000, 2000000, 2500.01]})
df["Dollars Formatted"] = df["Dollar Amount"].apply(lambda x: "$"+lc.format("%.2f",x,True))
```

The convenient thing about `locale` is that you can easily change between different number conventions if you need to, and it will continue to apply those conventions for the millions and billions separators.

Answer (score 2):

using map:

```
df['Dollar Amount'] = df['Dollar Amount'].map("{:,}".format)
```

you can also use style which is nicer and let you do all your styling in one line:

```
df = df.style.format({'Dollar Amount': "{:,}"})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert thousands comma separators in a *specific column* and *remove the decimal place*:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([(0.21, 1000.0), (0.01, 2000000.0), (0.66, 1000.0), (0.21, 330000.0)], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Before:

```
      A          B
0  0.21     1000.0
1  0.01  2000000.0
2  0.66     1000.0
3  0.21   330000.0
```

For "Col B" insert comma separators and remove decimal place: A slight adjustment to *YOBEN_S's* code above gives:

```
lst = list(df.columns)
lst.remove('A')
for c in lst:
    df[c] = df[c].astype(int).apply(lambda x: f'{x:,}')
```

After:

```
      A          B
0  0.21      1,000
1  0.01  2,000,000
2  0.66      1,000
3  0.21    330,000
```

Answer (score 0):

The f string version of [@Benny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404538/14036406):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'DollarAmount': [5012.82, 1203, 4000.0, 824.07, 625.0]})
df.DollarAmount.apply(lambda x: f"{x:,}")

0    5,012.82
1     1,203.0
2     4,000.0
3      824.07
4       625.0
Name: DollarAmount, dtype: object
```