# How to transform numbers in data-frame column to comma separated

Tags: python, pandas

i am working with python , so in my dataframe i have a column named `Company Profit` and values of this column are `33536310, 842925200,.. etc.`

I want to convert all values to be comma separated every three digits, like: `231,535,366`  etc in whole column

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: will it work if i try like slicing last 3 digit as string and concatenate comma?

Comment: Provide a data sample (in text), and minimal code.

Comment: Country
China                 1367643161.29
United States         317615384.615
Japan                 127403595.973
United Kingdom        63870967.7419
Russian Federation      143500000.0
Canada                35233864.8649
Germany               80379996.9697
India                 1276730769.23
France                63837349.3976
South Korea           49805429.8643
Italy                 59908256.8807
Spain                 46443396.2264
Iran                  77075630.2521
Australia              23316017.316
Brazil                205915254.237

Comment: sorry column cant fit in

Comment: i want to make digits comma separated

Comment: this is one column of data frame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a comma as a thousands separator in a pandas dataframe column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404472/how-to-insert-a-comma-as-a-thousands-separator-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
In [601]: def thousand_separator(val): 
     ...:     return f"{val:,}"  
     ...: 

In [602]: df['Company Profit'] = df['Company Profit'].apply(thousand_separator) 
In [603]: df['Company Profit']                                                                                                                                                              
Out[602]: 
0     33,536,310
1    842,925,200
Name: Profit, dtype: object
```

Comment: i have tried but it is saying that thousand_separator is not defined. I have imported pandas as well as numpy

Comment: @wm50 I have already created `thousand_separator` function above. You also copy paste it first. Then run the commands below it.

Comment: where is the option to accept? actually i m new here

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do this with `f-string` in newer version of Python. Use comma as a separator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Company Profit':[33536310,842925200,231535366]})
df['Company Profit'] = df['Company Profit'].apply(lambda x: f"{x:,}")
print(df)

  Company Profit
0     33,536,310
1    842,925,200
2    231,535,366
```