# How format different numeric values in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, numbers

I have a column in dataframe with 1000+ row and different numeric values. How can i replace these values and have unified view?
I would like to have this view **1.000.000** for each rows that doesn't have.

For example.

```
***Sales***

100,0

1.000.000

10000000

0,100000
```

Output desiderated

***Sales***

100.000

1.000.000

10.000.000

100.000

Comment: please add your input & output dataframes.

Comment: So, are you asking "how can I format the numbers in this column?"  You can check here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-with-commas-to-separate-thousands-in-python, but you'll need to convert your strings to numbers first.

Comment: I added an output

Comment: Yes, did you read the link?  You should keep your columns as integers (not strings), and then use the options.display to determine how they are printed.

Comment: Yes i read. Thanks