# Convert Million to integer in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change the scraped results in a column called "Outstanding". Currently, the numbers being scraped are coming out like 297.5M and I want them to be 297,500,000. I'm not sure quite how to do it but I know that if you put e5 instead of M, it would come out as 297500000. I tried this below but no luck. Any ideas how to get what I'm looking for.  Thanks

```
 data.replace({
            'Outstanding': {
                'M': 'e5'
            }
        })

    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import bs4
    import time
    import random
    
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
    
    def get_screener(version):
        url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=all&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap'
        
        page = 1
       
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
        pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
          
        data = []
        for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
            print(version, page)
            screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
            tables = pd.read_html(screen)
            tables = tables[-2]
            tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
            tables = tables[1:]
            data.append(tables)
            time.sleep(random.random())
        return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
           
    df = get_screener('152')
    
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    
    
    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    
    # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
    
    header_format = workbook.add_format()
    header_format.set_font_name('Calibri')
    header_format.set_font_color('green')
    header_format.set_font_size(8)
    header_format.set_italic()
    header_format.set_underline()
    
    # Write the column headers with the defined format.
    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
    
    # Add some cell formats.
    format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
    format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
    format3 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
    
    data.replace({
        'Outstanding': {
            'M': 'e5'
        }
    })
    
    # Note: It isn't possible to format any cells that already have a format such
    # as the index or headers or any cells that contain dates or datetimes.
    
    # Set the column width and format.
    worksheet.set_column('AA:AA', 18, format1)
    
    # Set the format but not the column width.
    worksheet.set_column('B:C', None, format3)    
    
    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()

**Updated Code**
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import time
import random

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def get_screener(version):
    url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=131&f=sh_outstanding_o1'
    
    page = 1
   
    screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
    pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
      
    data = []
    for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
        print(version, page)
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        data.append(tables)
        time.sleep(random.random())
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)
       
df = get_screener('131')

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')


# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

header_format = workbook.add_format()
header_format.set_font_name('Calibri')
header_format.set_font_color('green')
header_format.set_font_size(8)
header_format.set_italic()
header_format.set_underline()

# Write the column headers with the defined format.
for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

# Add some cell formats.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})

get_screener('131').Outstanding = get_screener('131').Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('MB'))*1000000):,.2f}")

# Note: It isn't possible to format any cells that already have a format such
# as the index or headers or any cells that contain dates or datetimes.

# Set the column width and format.
worksheet.set_column('AA:AA', 18, format1)

# Set the format but not the column width.
worksheet.set_column('B:C', None, format3)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()



    No. Ticker Market Cap Outstanding  ... Avg Volume   Price  Change   Volume
0      1      A     48.27B     304.70M  ...      1.53M  160.88   0.14%   756185
1      2     AA     11.07B     187.00M  ...      8.65M   59.21  -0.70%  4378041
2      3    AAC      1.22B     125.00M  ...    271.23K    9.74   0.00%    60427
3      4   AACG     32.13M      31.19M  ...     45.85K    1.04  -1.89%   116352
4      5   AADI    499.64M       9.51M  ...    181.05K   24.87   4.36%    66884
...   ..    ...        ...         ...  ...        ...     ...     ...      ...
6035  16   AATC     33.53M       5.34M  ...     19.10K    6.28  -2.40%    12875
6036  17    AAU     41.57M     137.22M  ...    663.16K    0.30   3.26%   665062
6037  18   AAWW      2.69B      29.02M  ...    522.66K   93.25  -0.54%   364687
6038  19     AB      4.72B      99.41M  ...    275.59K   49.01   0.51%   176291
6039  20    ABB     76.14B       2.00B  ...      1.43M   38.14  -1.32%  1367408
```

Edit

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import bs4
import time
import random

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}

def testDf(version):
    url = 'https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v={version}&r={page}&f=sh_outstanding_o1000&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70&f=ind_stocksonly&o=-marketcap'

    page = 1

    screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(screen.text, features='lxml')
    pages = int(soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'screener-pages'})[-1].text)
    
    data = []
    for page in range(1, 20 * pages, 20):
        print(version, page)
        screen = requests.get(url.format(version=version, page=page), headers=headers).text
        tables = pd.read_html(screen)
        tables = tables[-2]
        tables.columns = tables.iloc[0]
        tables = tables[1:]
        data.append(tables)
        time.sleep(random.random())
    return pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(columns=None)

df = testDf('152')
def converter(x):
    if 'M' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}"
    elif 'B' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('B'))*1000000000):,.2f}"

# Print first 20 rows of head to see current values
print(testDf('152').Outstanding.head(20))
# Call the apply method
testDf('152').Outstanding = testDf('152').Outstanding.apply(converter)

# Print first 20 rows of head to see modified values
print(testDf('152').Outstanding.head(20))
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We don't need code to scrape a web page and get your data. Instead, show us simple, hard-coded data. We don't need code that makes an Excel spreadsheet with fancy formatting. According to you, the *problem you are trying to solve* is specifically about manipulating the Dataframe, so the code you show us should be *focused* on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102734/format-a-number-with-commas-to-separate-thousands-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['297.5M']], columns=['Outstanding'])
>>> data
```

[image]

Convert:

```
data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: float(x.strip('M'))*1000000)
>>> data
```

[image]

*** Edit ***

Further to the comment below, if you want commas:

```
data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}")
>>> data
```

[image]

However, your value will now be a string.

*** Edit ***

[image]

*** Edit ***

If you also want to remove possible B's (as in 260B), use this code:

```
data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('MB'))*1000000):,.2f}
```

***** Edit *****

```
# Create the conversion function
def converter(x):
    if 'M' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}"
    elif 'B' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('B'))*1000000000):,.2f}"

# Print first 20 rows of head to see current values
print(testDf.Outstanding.head(20))
```

[image]

```
# Call the apply method
testDf.Outstanding = testDf.Outstanding.apply(converter)

# Print first 20 rows of head to see modified values
print(testDf.Outstanding.head(20))
```

[image]

***** EDIT *****

Replace the portion of your code that begins with the first statement in the code below:

```
# Copy from here on below

df = testDf('152')

def converter(x):
    if 'M' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}"
    elif 'B' in x:
        return f"{(float(x.strip('B'))*1000000000):,.2f}"

# Print first 20 rows of the Outstanding column of 
# the dataframe to see current values
print(df.Outstanding.head(20))

# Call the apply method on the Outstanding column
df.Outstanding = df.Outstanding.apply(converter)

# Print first 20 rows of the Outstanding column of 
# the dataframe to see values after being converted
print(df.Outstanding.head(20))

# The newly converted dataframe is in the df variable
print(df)
```

Little plus: there are four columns in your dataframe that are formatted with "999M|B". If you wanted to change all of them to the long format, replace `df.Outstanding = df.Outstanding.apply(converter)` with:

```
# Conveert all M/B columns in one go:
listToConvert = ['Outstanding', 'Market Cap', 'Float', 'Avg Volume']
for column in listToConvert:
    df[column] = df[column].apply(converter)

print(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I think what he wants is number with ',' comma tho

Comment: So, how would I convert an entire column of numbers, not just 297.5M? Sorry but I'm a novice.

Comment: See edit. However, dtype will now be an object/string.

Comment: @vinnyrusso The apply() method will be applied to every value in the column. See my edit above.

Comment: The way I understand it, the numbers are being scraped from a table and put into a dataframe and then I was hoping to convert the entire column numbers like 297.5M before being exported to excel. So, I'm not listing the individual numbers, 297.M, 22.5M out in the code. If I'm misunderstanding, sorry. – 
vinny russo
 43 mins ago

Comment: My apologies but I'm not sure I understand your comment. Maybe post a view of the dataframe in question? The code above (and edits) will provide you with a column containing the converted amounts (i.e.: from 297.5M -- to -- > 297,500,000.00 and so on). What were you looking for specifically? (p.s.: the dataframe in my last edit was created **just as an example**. If I understand corrrectly, your dataframe should already contain a column filled with values which you would like to convert)

Comment: I’m saying I can’t put 297.5M in the code you provided when I don’t know what the actual numbers will be since they are being scraped from a table. = pd.DataFrame([['297.5M']], columns=['Outstanding'])

Comment: This is the line of code you will need:
`data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}")`
Everything else is just an example.
That line of code will work on the values located in a column named "Outstanding" in a dataframe named "Data". You can change "Outstanding" and "Data" to whatever you wish to match your code.

Comment: Thanks!!Seems like it was working but then hit a number with Billion, 260B and bombed out. I tried to add similar code for a Billion but must be doing something wrong.?

Comment: Ah, you only mentionned M not B. For M and B use this code: `data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('MB'))*1000000):,.2f}"`

Comment: Hi, I updated the code in the original post.  It ran through with no errors, however  the millions and billions were not updated? I must have screwed something up.

Comment: Can you show me what the column in question looks like in the dataframe.

Comment: I apologize but I don't know how to produce what you're requesting.  I did put a link to the excel output.

Comment: Actually, i just realized that this code:
`data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}")`
will only do millions as it multiplies by 1,000,000.

For billions, the value would need to be multiplied accordingly:
`data.Outstanding = data.Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('B'))*1000000000):,.2f}")`

Comment: In the excel output, I still only see numbers like 304.70M and 48.27B. That's the final excel output?

Comment: I put both lines in the code but I get this error. get_screener('131').Outstanding = get_screener('131').Outstanding.apply(lambda x: f"{(float(x.strip('M'))*1000000):,.2f}")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '16.49B'

Comment: Yeah simply putting both codes in without an "if, elif" statement to check whether the value is in billions or millions before applying one or the other of the codes won't work. You have to add an if, elif statement e.g.: if 'M' then run this code....elif 'B' run this code. Are you able to print the df? (df = get_screener('131'))

Comment: I just printed the df and put it at the bottom of the original post.  I was messing around with the if, elif stuff but I think it would take me a year to pull that off. Lol

Comment: I ran the first half of your code to get the dataframe which i called `testDf`. Then I ran the `Outstanding` column through the converter I wrote in my latest edit above. Look at the results. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: I can't reproduce those results for some reason.  I even made a table with just billions and used the original code you provided but it didn't work. Not sure why but nothing seems to work?

Comment: The thing is I ran this code on the dataframe created from your own code and got the result you see in the edit. How are you inserting the code (e.g.: where)? Just to be clear, we're talking about my very last edit with the converter() function.

Comment: I made an edit where I use your code but unlike your results, mine are exactly the same after running the converter? Where am I going wrong?  Thanks

Comment: Ok @vinnyrusso, i;ve re-read your code and made just a few minor adjustments. Run the code in my edit and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Working Great!  Thanks for sticking with this.  I learned a lot.

Comment: You're very welcome! Cheers brother.