# Pandas to_csv truncating string values to exponent notation

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am adding a column to my dataframe like:

`df['AccountID'] = "123456789765"`.

I am assigning it a string value.
Then I am writing the dataframe to a csv file using the to_csv method.
But in the csv file the column values appear like: `1.23456E+11`.

Can someone tell the reason and solution for this ?

I've already tried casting the column to object type again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppressing scientific notation in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas)

Comment: I don't think so. Actually my column itself is all strings(with the same value). When I am printing the dataframe in Pycharm it shows all correct values, but in the csv it is somehow getting converted(truncated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel/452845#452845)

> Unfortunately excel does not allow you to turn this functionality off
>   by default.
>
> However if you select your data, right click, and click "Format
>   cells..." and choose Number you can stop excel from changing your data
>   to scientific notation.

e.g. it's not a pandas issue.

Comment: Ya I was actually trying to get the csv file into power bi. Guess I'll have to do a similar thing there then.

Comment: I haven't used Power BI, but I would imagine yes.