# Pandas reading scientific data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv-file with many columns containing something like

```
"4.2515014131285567e-001"
```

Pandas reads it as an **object**, therefore calculation doesn't make sense.

For example `*2` gives me:

```
"4.2515014131285567e-0014.2515014131285567e-001"
```

How can I use it as a number and doing some math stuff?

I tried to set `"dtype=str" "dtype=float"` and such things but nothing worked.

Comment: Looks somehow similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17737300/4636715

Comment: If you only have columns with values like your example. Try `df = df.astype(float)` And then try your calculations

Comment: thanks, I'm facing a problem: In the table is some string, this I would like to delete. This row is starting with a string "info" and I would like to delete this row and every row below. How can I do this? From top I can use "skiprows", how can I do this from the bottom? And how can I skip a specific column?

Comment: Okay, I found a solution for deleting rows. Now df.astype(float) works :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some pre-processing, you can convert the data on import and remove non-float records prior to importing if they exist.

Initial dataset in test.txt:

```
Math
4.2515014131285567e-001
asdas
123123
asdasd124
123
125423414asd
```

This tests if float, and if so it'll return true/false while creating a list of values to skip.

```
def isFloat(val):

    try:
        float(val)
        return True

    except:
        return False

with open('test.txt','r') as f:

    skiplines=[]

    for i, v in enumerate(f.readlines()):

        if not isFloat(v.split(',')[0]):

            skiplines.append(i)

# we want to maintain the column header.
    del skiplines[0]



converter = {'NumberColName':lambda x: float(x)}

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt', converters = converter, skiprows= skiplines)
```

The lambda function can also just be declaring a data type.  I like demonstrating the converters because you can easily round or apply logic here if you need it.

The final dataframe looks as expected (note that there are 0's because I have not set my format.

```
print(df)
           Math
0       0.42515
1  123123.00000
2     123.00000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following test:

Create the following DataFrame, using *read_csv*, but from a text buffer:

```
txt = '''c1,c2,c3
Xxxxx,4.2515014131285567e-001,4.2515014131285555e-001
Yyyyy,4.2515014131284444e-001,4.2515014131283333e-001
Zzzzz,4.2515014131282222e-001,4.2515014131281111e-001'''
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(txt))
```

Then check types of columns with `df.info()`.
For both *c2* and *c3* columns you should receive *float64* type.

If you execute `df.c2 * 2`, you should receive doubled values.
Don't bother about smaller number of decimal digits.
It is the matter of *Pandas* options.

You can display an individual number with almost full precision, using `df.loc[0, 'c2']`
(I got `0.4251501413128557`).

The same results should be even if numbers were surrounded with e.g. double quotes.

Up to now it was OK, but now try the second test:

In row 3, *c2* column, remove *e* in front of *-001*, so this value is now
*4.2515014131282222-001* and *read_csv* again.

The value changed is **not** any properly formatted *float*, so *read_csv*
assumes for *c2* column **object** type, actually a *string* (you can confirm it
with `df.info()`).

My assumption is that somewhere in your text file the format of a number
is somehow "corrupted" and just this prevents *read_csv* from reading
this column as *float*.

To find the place - source of this error, run:

```
df.c2 = pd.to_numeric(df.c2, errors='coerce')
```

(replacing *c2* with the proper column name) and then look in this column
for *NaN* values.

Then look at the corresponding row in the input file and correct the error.

Alternative: `df.dropna(inplace=True)` removes each row containig *NaN* in any
column. You may also add *subset=['column_name']* parameter, to drop rows
with *NaN* in just this one column.