# Suppress scientific notation in Pandas *without* altering precision

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point

Is there a way to suppress scientific notation in Panda's outputs *without* forcing a particular precision across all columns?

So that a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [0.01, 0.02, 0.03], "b": [0.0000001, 0.0000002, 0.0000003]})

df.to_csv(
    "df.csv",
    index=False,
)
```

That initially would be outputted as:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 1.00E-07 |
| 0.02 | 2.00E-07 |
| 0.03 | 3.00E-07 |

Instead becomes my desired output:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0.01 | 0.0000001 |
| 0.02 | 0.0000002 |
| 0.03 | 0.0000003 |

Many questions about suppressing scientific notation in Pandas' .to_csv results have already [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737300/suppressing-scientific-notation-in-pandas) [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137150/format-suppress-scientific-notation-from-python-pandas-aggregation-results), but all of the answers involve specifying an arbitrary precision.

For instance, setting `float_format="%.7f"` in `df.to_csv` forces 7 significant digits for all float columns and numbers (and so does `round(7)`, of course).

This would lead to the following output, which I don't want:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0100000 | 0.0000001 |
| 0.0200000 | 0.0000002 |
| 0.0300000 | 0.0000003 |

(I also tried using `np.format_float_positional` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58106536/1569221), but had no luck.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `np.format_float_positiona`l on a series. If done on df, you will be forced to iterate which can be quite computationally expensive.

**Pd.Series**

```
df['b'] =[(lambda x: np.format_float_positional(x))(x) for x in df['b']]
```

or simply as suggested by @user2357112 supports Monica

```
df['b'] =[np.format_float_positional(x) for x in df['b']]
```

**Def function**
Lets try putting this in def function

```
import numpy as np

def format_float(df):
    
    cols=list(df.columns)
    for col in cols:
        df[col]=[np.format_float_positional(x) for x in df[col]]
        
    return df

format_float(df)
```

**outcome**

```
 a          b
0  0.01  0.0000001
1  0.02  0.0000002
2  0.03  0.0000003
```

Comment: The `lambda` is unnecessary. You could just write `[np.format_float_positional(x) for x in df['b']]`.

Comment: You are right, hangover of temptation to iterate over df I guess. Will edit

Comment: Also, you're still iterating. You can't avoid that just by operating on a series.

Comment: Maybe post that as answer

Comment: How did you go @user2357112 supports Monica

Comment: This does the trick @wwnde! Could I suggest simplifying your answer for readability by dropping everything before the code block where you define `format_float`? I think everything before that is basically unnecessary.